# Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally

Tags: docker

I have installed docker in my machine following the official installation steps for ubuntu. At the verification steps it fails.

When I run the command: docker run hello-world it throws following error message:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry- 
1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for 
connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Below are the docker details for my machine.

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.6
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.12.16
Git commit:        369ce74a3c
Built:             Thu Feb 13 01:27:49 2020
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

If I tried for docker info I got the following message:

> Client:
>    Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
errors pretty printing info

Comment: Your current user is not in the `docker` group and hence does not have necessary permissions to communicate with the docker daemon => `sudo usermod -a -G docker yourUserName`

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.4, a system restart fixed the issue and I was able to see output.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply pull and test it in this way:

```
$ sudo docker pull hello-world
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 3):

First check if docker is running using

> sudo service docker status

If its running, then you probably missed out adding your user to docker group. To confirm this, try docker commands with **sudo**

If you don't want to use **sudo** every time follow below guide to add you user to docker group

[Step 2 — Executing the Docker Command Without Sudo (Optional)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04)

NOTE : You can not run Docker in WSL i.e Ubuntu on Windows, so you need to install docker for windows, following guide provided complete steps of using Docker in WSL.

[Setting Up Docker for Windows and WSL to Work Flawlessly](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)

Comment: Not sure if WSL or Docker were updated, but I have had success with running docker inside WSL by simply using this guide https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Docker is not installed on my windows 11 machine.

Comment: Windows 11 is more flexible when it comes to supporting linux based products, so it is higly possible this answer is valid only till Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Post installation steps of docker are probably not executed. Basically, the current logged in used need to be added to `docker` group.

Just follow the instructions here from docker documentation - https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

FYA- group membership evaluation would happen only after a reboot of ubuntu (in 18.04).  So, after following the above link, reboot ubuntu machine. Then try `docker images` and permission issue reported should get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has solved when I upgrade my ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, while trying to fix the below error,

> root@neno88:/home/mohan# docker run hello-world Unable to find image
> 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get
> https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup
> registry-1.docker.io on 10.187.215.112:53: read udp
> 10.187.215.103:58777->10.187.215.112:53: read: connection refused.

So, The error was due to the proxy in my enterprise setup, the daemon requests are refused via proxy

WRONG TRY to fix it, ( which caused error like above.)
I have added the registry-1.docker.io ip to the /etc/hosts, but it caused the similar error as in this StackOverflow here.

> root@neno88:/home/mohan# docker run hello-world Unable to find image
> 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get
> https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
> waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers). See 'docker run --help'. root@neno88:/home/mohan#

CORRECT STEPS:
How to fix it,

1. Just add your Proxy details to the /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf (folder docker.service.d may not exists , so create the directory before)
2. After adding the proxy details check using the below commands , whether the daemon successfully see/read your environment variables.

> $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

> $ sudo systemctl restart docker

> $ systemctl show --property=Environment docker

Refer this doc: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-docker-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

In my case disconnecting from VPN solved the problem.